# Separate output of awk script with "space" not "enter"

Tags: awk

I know normally the output of an awk script was separated with enter. 
For example the script below:

```
awk '{print $1}' f.txt
```

The file f.txt's content is like:

```
awk bwk cwk
dwk ewk fwk
gwk hwk iwk
```

Then the output of the script would be like:

```
awk
dwk
gwk
```

Is there any way to get the output like

```
awk dwk gwk
```

?

Answer (score 2):

you do so can using `printf`:

```
awk '{printf $1" "}' f.txt
```

Unlike `print` the `printf` function in awk does not add a newline. The `" "` following `printf` gives the required spacing character after each field.

Comment: In general, it's probably safer to use `awk '{printf "%s ", $1}' f.txt` because if the column contains something like `%s`, you might get "*not enough arguments to satisfy format string*" error

Answer (score 2):

One way is to manipulate the Output Field Separator; the OFS.

```
awk 'BEGIN {ORS = " "} {print $1}' f.txt
```

By default, the ORS is a newline, but this sets it to a space.

Comment: It can also be set with `awk -v ORS=" " '{print $1}' f.txt`.

Comment: Also `awk '{print $1}' ORS=" " f.txt`

Answer (score 1):

You need this:

```
awk '{printf "%s%s",(++n==1?"":" "),$1} END{print ""}' file
```

or if you prefer:

```
awk '{printf "%s%s",ofs,$1; ofs=OFS} END{print ""}' file
```

to avoid adding an undesirable space character at the end of the line and to terminate with a newline.